# jQuery navigating the dom with Each and Nth Child

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to navigate through each of the tr element and select the 5th td element then store the value in it. What am I doing wrong?

```
 $("table tbody tr td tbody tr:nth-child(4)").each(function (i) {
    alert(this.text);
  });
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table cellpadding="2" style="border: 2px solid rgb(208, 208, 208); border-spacing: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);">
        <tbody>
          <tr bgcolor="#e0e0e0">
            <th>Seller</th>
            <th>Feedback</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th/>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#e0e0e0">
            <td><a href="http://www.foo.com/">test3</a> </td>
            <td align="right"><a href="http://www.foo.com/User/1857/Feedback.html">+366</a> </td>
            <td>Near Mint English</td>
            <td align="right">8</td>
            <td align="right">12.49</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.foo.com/">Add to Cart</a> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
            <td><a href="http://www.foo.com/">test4</a> </td>
            <td align="right"><a href="http://www.foo.com/User/637/Feedback.html">+1,257</a> </td>
            <td>Near Mint English</td>
            <td align="right">14</td>
            <td align="right">13.58</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.foo.com/">Add to Cart</a> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#e0e0e0">
            <td><a href="http://www.foo.com/">test5</a> </td>
            <td align="right"><a href="http://www.foo.com/User/2989/Feedback.html">+2,062</a> </td>
            <td>Very Fine English</td>
            <td align="right">2</td>
            <td align="right">13.99</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.foo.com/">Add to Cart</a> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:nth-child` is applied to the child selector, not the parent:

```
$("table tbody tbody td:nth-child(5)").each(function (i) {
        alert(this.text);
});
```

I also removed un-needed selectors from your selection string.

**Correction** I just changed `:nth-child(4)` to `:nth-child(5)` because the `nth-child` selector is `1` based not `0` based like an index.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thought it was the parent. Thank you!

Comment: @Frederico, and be sure to note the change from `4` to `5` since it is not zero based. I updated my answer seconds before you accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

The `:nth-child` selector should be on the table cell, not the row, ie:

```
$("table tbody tr td tbody tr td:nth-child(4)")
```

By the way, you can clean this up a lot by ignoring the rows/cells of the outer table:

```
$("table table tr > :nth-child(4)")
```

I would also suggest adding a class on that nested table if possible in order to shorten your selector.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, nth-child is 1 indexed, so to get the 5th child, you need nth-child(5).  Also, your selector will select the 4th row, not the 5th child of the row, so what you want is

```
$("table tbody tbody tr td:nth-child(5)")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between `tr` and `:nth-child`.

So:

```
$("table tbody tr td tbody tr > :nth-child(4)")...
```

This expression:

```
tr:nth-child(4)
```

means every tr that ***is*** the fourth child but:

```
tr :nth-child(4)
```

means every descendant of `tr` that is a fourth child. To restrict it just to children:

```
tr > :nth-child(4)
```

And since you want only `<td>` elements:

```
tr > td:nth-child(4)
```

should do it making the final expression:

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)")
```

Comment: Also, he wants the fifth td, not just the fifth child.